# g++ is installed but when I try to run it I'm told it is not installed

Tags: ubuntu, g++

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and I have g++ installed:

```
~$ sudo apt install g++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
g++ is already the newest version (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

However, when I try to use it to compile, or if I just call it, I receive an error message stating that g++ is not installed.

```
~$ g++
The program 'g++' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install g++
```

I already tried `apt update` and `apt upgrade` but nothing changes. Build essential package is also installed:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How can I have g++ working?

Comment: try to do `gcc --version`

Comment: Have you tried removing it and reinstalling it?

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne: gcc (Ubuntu 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~16.04) 6.2.0 20160901

Comment: @JohnZwinck Nice, it just worked. used `sudo apt-get install --reinstall g++`

Answer (score 2):

Something is wrong with the installation, or it has since been modified/broken.

Reinstall it.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall g++
```